# Delete keys using regex in memcache

Tags: memcached

Can i delete multiple keys in one go having similar key name in memcache using regex?

e.g. keys are:

```
key1
key2
key3

command [key.]
```

What "command" to use which should delete all of **key1**, **key2**, and **key3**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Memcached does not have an option to delete keys with regex. You can delete cached data per key, or flush the whole cache.

If you have similar keys, you might look at official wiki for [Memcached namspacing](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki/ProgrammingTricks#namespacing).

e.g. instead of having your keys in Memcached saved in like this:

```
key1
key2
key3
```

you could organize keys in namespaces, they would now look like this:

```
key:<namespace_value>:1
key:<namespace_value>:2
key:<namespace_value>:3
```

where **namespace_value** is some random integer, which you would keep in Memcached as well, per cache region (with prefix *"key"* ) For example, if your cache data looks like this:

```
<key>            <value>
namespace:key       1234
key:1234:1        value1
key:1234:2        value2
key:1234:3        value3
```

Now before you access your key, you will fetch the **namespace_value** first, and append it to your key.

- Fetch value for **namespace:key** (results in `1234`)
- Fetch the value for **key1** within namespace; your actual lookup key would be `key:<namespace_value>:1` => **key:1234:1**

Now to evict all keys with prefix *"key"* it is sufficient to increment **namespace_value**, and save it back in your cache. Now your namespace value would be **1235**, and cache data will be:

```
<key>            <value>
namespace:key      1235
key:1234:1        value1
key:1234:2        value2
key:1234:3        value3
```

The next fetch for **key1** with the new namespace value will search for **key:1235:1**, and will give you a miss. Therefore, you have evicted the cache for all your keys.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this doesn't seem a promising approach and no better way in memcache to solve this problem.What other caching service can i use in which such operations are easily done and also doesn't compromise much on speed?

Comment: With Memcached it's only delete per key or flush all data. Then to achieve something different, it's all about organizing your cached data in a different way.

You could check [Redis](https://redis.io/), it might suit your needs more. There is (KEYS pattern)[https://redis.io/commands/keys] command, that might be something you're looking for, but do read the **Warning** section. It's not recommended for production use, since it might have an impact on your performance.